# Windows 8 XAML Multilingual Translations

Tags: xaml, windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I've used the Multilingual Toolkit to translate my app and have been testing it using pseudo-language. It works fine for strings I have translated in code (C#) but I can't work out how to make it so that the tag in XAML is automatically translated.

I've been using http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh965329.aspx as a tutorial but I can't figure it out. I've also searched on Google but still no luck.

For example, I created a "Watermark" text box (which inherits from `TextBox` which shows some text in by default it the user has not entered any text and the item does not have focus. The XAML looks like this (I replaced generic positioning stuff with '...'):

```
<local:WatermarkTextbox x:Name="TitleTextBox" Watermark="MainPage_EnterATitle" ... Style="{StaticResource TextBoxStyle1}" />
```

As you can see it is setting a property called `Watermark` with a 'tag' of the resource name that is being translated using the Multilingual tool. I'm not sure how to get this to automatically translate.

Another example is using the bottom app bar buttons:

```
<Button x:Name="bottomAppBar_unpinFromStartButton" AutomationProperties.Name="MainPage_UnpinFromStart" Style="{StaticResource UnPinAppBarButtonStyle}" Click="bottomAppBar_unpinFromStartButton_Click"/>
```

And I can see in the link above that it says:

```
MediumButton.[using:Windows.UI.Xaml.Automation]AutomationProperties.Name
```

But I'm not really sure where this is meant to go.

Even with a button, which seems like it would be the simplest to translate I can't get it to work. The XAML is:

```
<Button x:Name="RemovePhotoButton" x:Uid="MainPage_RemovePhoto" Content="" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="222,0,974,78" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="170" Height="45"/>
```

But when ran in the app or viewed in the designed the button stays blank, with no text on it.

The Resources are set up like this:

[image]

And it is filling the translated documents fine:

[image]

I am able to translate it in C# using the code from the link above, just not using XAML.

Just wondering if anybody could help me out or point me in the right direction to solve this.

Thanks

Comment: not sure I understand "tag in the XAML is automatically translated".  The x:Uid is essentially a key looked up in the resource file and then you provide localized values for properties of interest - like Greeting.Text in the sample. Did the QuickStart you linked to not work for you?  What error/behavior did you see with that specific example?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I have updated the main post with some extra information that should hopefully clear things up.

Comment: Let's start with the simple case - the button - what does your resource file look like (contents and name/folder hierarchy)? It looks like it's not matching the current culture, so nothing is picked up.

Comment: Set up like this:
http://i.imgur.com/ahKFk.png

It is filling the translated documents fine:
http://i.imgur.com/QLpB9.png

And I am able to translate it in code using the code from the link in the original question.

Comment: by "translate it in code" I mean using C#, not XAML.

Comment: Just posting to ask if you haven't replied as you don't know the answer or if you have just forgotten. Thanks.

Comment: Are you referring to localization? Because then you need resource files which will translate all your text to the given language
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms788718.aspx

Comment: If you read the comments above, I do have translated documents created by the Multilingual Resource Tool. Is this not what is needed? I have edited the main question to show these images.

Comment: it looks like you have a solution below now?  just trying to determine the timeline.

Comment: Someone provided the answer after I wrote the comment above. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First what i think is missing in the name of your resources is the property that you want to set. While never used it myself, i would understand it like this:

Your xaml needs to be changed to

```
<local:WatermarkTextbox x:Name="TitleTextBox" x:Uid="MainPage_EnterATitle" Watermark="" ... Style="{StaticResource TextBoxStyle1}" />
```

And your resource needs an entry with the key

```
MainPage_EnterATitle.Watermark
```

And about the part with the

> MediumButton.[using:Windows.UI.Xaml.Automation]AutomationProperties.Name

This is only used if the referenced property is an attached property. Like if your Watermark property would be attached not part of the control. But in your case its not important.

Comment: I have tried this and it just makes the watermark blank (looks like it is setting the string as "" and not localising it at all)

Comment: Hm, can you try to do that in a very simply test, using a text box and the text property? I don't have a windows 8 development pc near me, otherwise i would try it.

Comment: It is also blank. The XAML is used was `<TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="835,505,0,0" Grid.Row="1" TextWrapping="Wrap" x:Uid="CreateDiary_RemoveCoverPhotoButtonText" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="223"/>` where the Uid is translated in the Multilingual Pseduo Language file as "[BB8D1][!!_Řémôνê Îmãĝę_!!]"

Comment: what was the resource key? CreateDiary_RemoveCoverPhotoButtonText.Text should be the correct one.

Comment: Ahhh, if I add ".Text" to the end of the resource key then it doesn't work in the designer but it does appear correctly when I run the app. Do you know a way to make it also appear in the app?

Comment: I will just enter the english version into the text so it looks OK in the designer. Do you know how to localise buttons on the app bar? It looks like I do have to use that automation properties thing.

Comment: to localize the app bar button text, your property name in the resource file would look like: myAppBarButton.[using:Windows.UI.Xaml.Automation]AutomationProperties.Name. And you'd have XAML in your page like <Button x:Uid="myAppBarButton" Style="{StaticResource AppBarButtonStyle}">foo</Button>